# Mysql Fetch Array Foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to use a foreach loop to set value to populate a table, for some reason my array is showing null inside values. But when I var dump the  $result_list[]  it shows the array of products, Am i doing this wrong?  Thanks

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, product, price FROM products");


$result_list = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $result_list[] = $row;
}

foreach($result_list as $row) {

    $productitems[] = array(
        'id' => $row->id,
        'product'  => $row->product,
        'price'  => $row->price
    );              
}

var_dump($productitems);


array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> NULL ["product"]=> NULL ["price"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> NULL ["product"]=> NULL ["price"]=> NULL } }
```

Comment: its not $row->id but its $row['id']

Comment: Do not use deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: `The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead`. Anyway. you need foreach($result_list[] as $row. you forgot the [].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach($result_list as $row) {

    $productitems[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'product'  => $row['product'],
        'price'  => $row['price']
    );              
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to,

```
foreach($result_list as $row) {
    $productitems[] = array(
       'id' => $row['id'],
       'product'  => $row['product'],
       'price'  => $row['price']
    );
}
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question you are getting back row as an array and not object but yet you still try to access it as an object `$row->id`. Instead use `$row['id']`, `$row['product']`, `$row['price']`.

Do not use mysql_* functions instead use PDO or MySQLi, for example look how simple it is with PDO:

```
$productitems = $pdo->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); and then use foreach
```